# Why bash script doesn't leave code immediately when "[: ==: unary operator expected"

Tags: bash

Is there any way let the bash script errors out and return non-zero exit code when facing `[: ==: unary operator expected` error?

I've searched online and tried to add `set -euxo pipefail` but none of these approaches work as expected. (Test on macOS and Linux).

```
$ ./a.sh
./a.sh: line 4: [: ==: unary operator expected
barfoo
$ echo $?
0
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
if [  == "foo" ];
then
  echo "foobar"
  exit 1
fi
echo "barfoo"
```

Bash prints `[: ==: unary operator expected` and continue to execute the rest of the code and return 0 in the end. I already know how to solve the "unary operator expected" problem, just curious what should I do to make the script to leave immediately with non-zero code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the left hand side of the `if` is blank because you're evaluating a variable, you can do `if [ "x$myvar" == "xfoo" ]` instead to work around that problem. If that's not the reason, can you tell us more about why it's blank?

Comment: @DaveGray Yes, I did that to avoid the problem in the end. But just wondering if there is another way to make the script to leave immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You must see a Bash script as a terminal. If you open a terminal and mistype a command, `chmox -x <file>` for instance, the terminal doesn't exit but instead it prints a warning and remains open for you to proceed your work.

Instead of typing lots and lots of commands, you let Bash execute it from a file.